# Select2 - multiple selection custom format selection

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

I'm using select2 in my angular web application, and i'm trying to achieve 
a custom format selection for multiple selection mode, that as far as i know 
is not supported by select2.

by default select2 in multiple selection mode, just puts in selection area all the selections side by side and when there is not enough space the selection area height is getting bigger.

what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

"item1, item2, item3..." ("..."  appears when there is not enough.)

I hope someone will suggest a reasonable solution for my needs,

Thanks,

Nadav.

Answer (score 0):

as shown here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2 this directive is deprecated; there is a new directive here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select, which appears to support multiple selections.  Having said that, your question is not entirely clear and perhaps some more information would enable a better answer.